# Posting Form Elements Values Starting with http://

Tags: php, html, forms

I have created a PHP script and tested it on localhost using vertrigo. It is working fine. I uploaded it on my web hosting server, it is not working there. It have an HTML form that is processed using PHP. When I submit the form, the browser displays the following error message:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /jobs2/abc.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Here is the HTML form code, that is not working:

```
<form name="jobslist" method="POST" action="abc.php">
   <input type="text" name="job[0]" value="http://example.com/1.html" />
   <input type="text" name="job[1]" value="http://example.com/2.html" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
</form>
```

I've corrected it by removing **http://** before the values of form elements, and it is working fine.

```
<form name="jobslist" method="POST" action="abc.php">
   <input type="text" name="job[0]" value="example.com/1.html" />
   <input type="text" name="job[1]" value="example.com/2.html" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
</form>
```

- I want to know, how I can make the first code working well without
  removing *http://* in form element values?
- Secondly, I also want to know, why server is not accepting values starting with *http://* ?

Comment: Special characters must be escaped

Comment: @pes502 — There are no special characters in the code (other then ones which are being used *as* special characters and so shouldn't be escaped)

Comment: I'd speculate that you have some kind of overly paranoid XSS filter running on the server. You should read the server logs for better error messages though.

Comment: @Quentin -- I've checked error log, it is not logging this error.
I also have tested it 3 hosting accounts. It is only working at ipage hosting but not working on other hosting accounts. As I've shared hosting account, so can't change PHP configuration.

Comment: Can any1 suggest me solution without making changes in server/php configuration. Is there any PHP function to make the value (starting with _http://_) acceptable for server?

Answer (score 0):

Such error may be caused by a server-side module, like `mod_security`, `mod_rpaf` or any other WAF (Web Application Firewall, eg in a reverse proxy).
You can list enabled modules using `apache2ctl -M`.

If you don't see any suspect module, you can try `php -m` and check there too ...

If mod_security is guilty, you should see infos in the file `/var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log`